# Managing (Dynamic) DNS Zone files with Puppet

Tags: debian, bind, puppet

I'm running a Debian 7.0 (Wheezy) server and I have a dynamic DNS setup wherein my clients make DHCP requests and the DHCP server updates the DNS zone files with whatever IP was assigned to each client. I want to manage this setup with Puppet. There's only one problem, though: I don't want Puppet clobbering my DNS records every time I push my manifests.
In any case, it doesn't make much sense for the zone files to be managed by Puppet in the first place, as they will normally be continuously updated. What I would like to do, however, is to have Puppet push "skeleton" zone files in their correct place when the DNS service (`bind9`) is first installed. The reason I want this is because I want to encapsulate all of the server configuration in one place so that with only a few manifests, I can clone the entire configuration of the server.

At first I wanted to have `file` resources for the zone files subscribe to the DNS server package and set `refreshonly` to `true`. The only problem is that `file` types don't have a `refreshonly parameter`. So obviously, this approach is a dead-end.

Is there a "correct" way of doing this? Perhaps with Augeas?

---

**Update**

I tried

```
augtool ls /files/etc/bind
```

and this returned *nothing*! It seems that Augeas is unable to parse my zone files for some reason. It seems Augeas is not the answer, then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!
In the [Puppet type reference](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file), an attribute of the `file` resource called `replace` turned out to be just what I needed. I quote from the above link:

> **replace**
>
> Whether to replace a file or symlink that already exists on the local system but whose content doesn’t match what the `source` or `content` attribute specifies. Setting this to `false` allows file resources to initialize files without overwriting future changes. Note that this only affects content; Puppet will still manage ownership and permissions. Defaults to `true`. Valid values are `true` (also called `yes`), `false` (also called `no`).

I simply added

```
replace => false
```

to my zone file resources and that did the trick.

---

**Edit**

I actually used `false` instead of `no` as I'm not really sure if the latter is supported (even though the doc. says it is); another similar boolean flag gave me a syntax error when I tried assigning it `yes`. So use `false` to be safe.